# Adding columns to Google Cloud SQL Database

Tags: python, google-cloud-sql

This may also be a "how to use SSL certs with Alembic migration" but either way - I cannot identify a reasonable method for simply editing the columns on a Google Cloud SQL table. There is documentation for BigQuery, but not for a basic MySQL instance.

For the record, the unreasonable method involves creating a new table with the new columns, copying the entire database over, then deleting the old database, recreating it with the new columns, then copy everything back over.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I WAS way overcomplicating things. Anyways, it was this simple:

```
statement = "ALTER TABLE Tweets ADD COLUMN DateAdded DateTime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
database.engine.execute(statement)
```